# intentService : why my onHandleIntent is never called?

Tags: java, android

I'm working with android xml rpc to mount a server. For that I'm using and intentService. The only problem is that when the server class is launched, my onHandleIntent which contains the server is never called.

I've made some research and I found someone who had the same problem, he managed solving it by using ***super class*** but I'm new in programming and didn't manage to do what he did ==> [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/eedecfdd0ddac430/f1c52d3a2e798bc6#f1c52d3a2e798bc6)

Here is my code:

```
package tfe.rma.ciss.be;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlrpc.android.MethodCall;
import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCServer;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

public class Server extends IntentService {
   public String myData="";
   public String streamTitle = "",path="";

   public void onCreate() {

        Log.d("Server", ">>>onCreate()");

    }

    public Server() {
        super("Server");


    }
    public void onStart (Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d("Server", ">>>Started()");    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Server", ">>>handlingIntent()");
        try {
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8214);
            XMLRPCServer server = new XMLRPCServer();
            Log.d("Server", ">>>opening on port" + socket);
            while (true) {
                Socket client = socket.accept();
                MethodCall call = server.readMethodCall(client);
                String name = call.getMethodName();
                if (name.equals("newImage")) {
                    ArrayList<Object> params = call.getParams();
                    // assume "add" method has two Integer params, so no checks done
                   myData = (String)( params.get(0));
                    //int i1 = (Integer) params.get(1);
                    server.respond(client, new Object[] {200});
                    /*intent = new Intent (this, ParseFunction.class);
                 startService (intent);  */

                    Toast.makeText(this, myData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>Started()"); 

                    Intent i = new Intent( this, B.class );

                    i.putExtra( "Azo", myData);


                   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity( i );

                } else {
                    server.respond(client, null);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

  }
```

Comment: Refer [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/) example.

Comment: @ Lalit Poptani:   i red the article but it doesn't say why my onHandle intent is not called. i have pretty the same code :(
I apprciate your help !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In case someone else wants the result here is what I should have done.  Adding superclass to `onCreate` `super.onCreate()` and change `onStart` by `onStartCommand` (plus its superclass `super.onStartCommand()`), now it works as a charm

```
package tfe.rma.ciss.be;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlrpc.android.MethodCall;
import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCServer;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

public class Server extends IntentService {
    public String myData="";
    public String streamTitle = "",path="";

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("Server", ">>>onCreate()");
    }

    public Server() {
        super("Server");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Server", ">>>handlingIntent()");
        try {
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8214);
            XMLRPCServer server = new XMLRPCServer();
            Log.d("Server", ">>>opening on port" + socket);

            while (true) {
                Socket client = socket.accept();
                MethodCall call = server.readMethodCall(client);
                String name = call.getMethodName();

                if (name.equals("newImage")) {
                    ArrayList<Object> params = call.getParams();
                    // assume "add" method has two Integer params, so no checks done
                    myData = (String)( params.get(0));
                    //int i1 = (Integer) params.get(1);
                    server.respond(client, new Object[] {200});
                    /*intent = new Intent (this, ParseFunction.class);
                    startService (intent);  */

                    Toast.makeText(this, myData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>Started()"); 

                    Intent i = new Intent( this, B.class );
                    i.putExtra( "Azo", myData);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity( i );
                } else {
                    server.respond(client, null);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 42):

If you got here and nothing worked, check your manifest looks like this:

```
    <service android:name=".subpackage.ServiceClassName" >
    </service>
```

And not like this:

```
    <service android:name=".subpackage.ServiceClassName" />
```

There's a problem with xml closing tags. The first one works. The second is legal but doesn't work.

Comment: Two things:  Really?  Also, usually, with an intentservice we would want to define an intent-filter anyways and as such usually end up with the first one.

Answer (score 20):

Get rid of `onStart()`. First, it is obsolete. Second, you are not chaining to the superclass, thereby preventing `IntentService` from doing its work.

Comment: i've got rid of onStart () (replaced it by onStartCommand () )and added two super class ==> now it works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue, it turned out the service definition was missing in the App manifest.

Adding:

```
<service
   android:name=".MyIntentServiceName"
   android:exported="false" />
```

solved the problem.

Comment: I had to set `android:exported="true"` for it to work.

Answer (score 15):

Just to sum up: In case you override onStartCommand, do not forget to call super:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

If not, check your manifest, see answer by [Mister Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13251830/797249).

Answer (score 5):

I was having this problem but only on some devices, more specifically on a Motorola Moto G 1st Gen (4.5" & 4G-less) and the solution was to include the FULL PACKAGE NAME in the Service description in the Manifest.

So changing 'mypackage.MyService' to 'com.android.myapp.mypackage.MyService' solved the onHandleIntent never being called.

Answer (score 3):

Some of you might get to this page because your `onHandleIntent()` method never gets called, despite you implemented everything just fine.

If it's your first service you try to test, you might not be awared of the importance of permissions. In that case check your permissions.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I removed the OnCreate method and it works like a charm now. LMK if it worked for you :)